# "flag provided but not defined: -enable_iam_login" when try to start google cloud sql proxy

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-iam, cloud-sql-proxy

I'm trying to connect Public cloud SQL instance using Cloud SQL IAM database authentication.

I have enabled "**cloudsql_iam_authentication**" flag and created a IAM service account granting necessary role

I followed this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/authentication

I used this command to connect to instance

`cloud_sql_proxy  -instances=my-project:us-central1:my-db-name=tcp:3306 -enable_iam_login`

Once I tried to connect to instance I'm getting following error

`flag provided but not defined: -enable_iam_login`

Comment: Given command-line uses the flag with one single dash only (probably a typo). Note that flags are prefixed with double-dashes, see [related test](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy/blob/10c66d3a1de9ef4131446ab6540837ea0c5fcdb7/cmd/root_test.go#L301).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using the latest version.

Also, note: there's a new v2 version of the Proxy which has a much easier to use interface. In v2 this becomes:

```
cloud-sql-proxy --auto-iam-authn --port 3306 my-project:us-central1:my-db
```

The [README](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy) has a lot more information including sample invocations.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using old version of Cloud SQL Proxy.

For [versions 1.33.3](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy/releases/tag/v1.33.3) and prior use the command-line flag `--enable_iam_login`.